# USB detect on Arduino DUE

Tags: arduino-due

I want to know when something is connected to USB port by blinking an LED.

I suppose have to check PB10 UOTGVBOF, but how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

What I'm going to say is probably not the most efficient way to do it, but it should work: if your DUE is used as gadget and you wnat to detect the presence of a master, connect a GPIO to the +Vcc line of the usb port and either poll or program an edge triggered interrupt to detect when the line goes high.

Comment: Got it working by testing some internal registers state. Thanks for the reoly though

Comment: @Siddharth Would you care to put your solution as an answer.  It'll help others who come by later with the same question.  Regards,